# Proving harmonic function is zero

Tags: vector-analysis, harmonic-functions

I'm having trouble with a homework assignment. This is the question:

Suppose that $\Omega \subset \!R^3$ is a path connected bounded region and that $f : \Omega \rightarrow \!R$ satisfies $\Delta f(\underline{x}) = 0 \space \forall \underline{x} \in \Omega$ and $f(\underline{x}) = 0 \space \forall \underline{x} \in \partial\Omega$

I need to prove that $f(\underline{x}) = 0 \space \forall \underline{x} \in \Omega$

Any hints will be useful. Thank you.

The question suggests using Green's first identity and the fact that if $\nabla f(\underline{x}) \equiv 0$, $f$ is constant on $\Omega$

Comment: Since $f$ is harmonic, it satisfies the maximum and minimum principles.

Comment: I think you meant the boundary of omega. Hint: use a connectivity argument.

Comment: What part of the suggestion are you having trouble with?

Comment: I think I'm meant to use Green's first identity to prove that the gradient of f is 0, but I'm having trouble with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, Green's first identity is of the form
$$ \int_{\partial \Omega} f\nabla g\cdot \mathbf{n}\, dA = \int_\Omega f\nabla^2 g + \nabla f\cdot \nabla g\, dV. $$

Now you only have one function of interest, so try setting $f=g$ in the identity, and see what your hypotheses can do to simplify both sides. Also, can $\nabla f\cdot \nabla f$ be negative on $\Omega$?

Can you use this to show that $\nabla f = 0$?